# how to setup codeigniter in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: codeigniter

I've installed Apache, mysql, php. I need to setup codeigniter now. Which version is suitable and please give me clear steps to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no version specific .. You can choose any but latest would be good. Just upload the codeigniter files to the var/www/html/project-name and you are good to go

Comment: I would recommend using the latest version of codeigniter. Just have to remember the new naming convention File names must have the first letter upper case as well as class names.

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/codeigniter-installation-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do much thing

> [Download](https://codeigniter.com/download) Codeigniter from site
>
> Create [virtual host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Add this inside the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myproj.dev
  <Directory /home/path/to/site>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

> Enable the Virtual-host `sudo a2ensite filename.conf`
>
> Edit `host` in `/etc/`

add this in next to loaclhost

`127.0.0.1  myproj.dev`

Comment: Awesome, Thank you :)
My senior help me do that

Comment: @ArunKumar happy to help :)